# Firebase Registration with Facebook causes problems with different credentials (the generated UID is not the same)

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase-authentication, uid

I am using a Facebook button to sign my user into the Firebase service. I save the user in my user database on Firebase.

At the first connection:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {[...]                 
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    guard let uid = user?.uid else {
        return
    }
```

But when I save that, the generated UID from Firebase Auth doesn't match with the UID I got before.

When I disconnect and reconnect everything matches. However I have 2 times the user with the wrong and correct UID.

What am I doing wrong?

I really appreciate your help

Joseph

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I have code the firebase with facebook button login. When a user log it s linked with Firebase facebook  authentification. I get the current UID number of this user with FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser and use this UID to create a new User data base. But at the first login of the user, i reallize that the UID in FB Authentification base doesn t match the UID from FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser  so in firebase it s create an entry with a wrong UID. When i log out and log in again, the FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser give me the correct UID matching with Authentification data so re create a new entry.

Comment: Find the solution to my problem, i need to collect UID directly at the level of 
 : FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
            print("something went wrong with FB user", error ?? "")
            return
            }
 //       })
   but not at FirAuth.auth()?.currentUser     
            guard let uid = user?.uid else {
                return
            }